# Search result ordering in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-search

we have portal in sharepoint 2007.
We have one document library with 2 custom columns named as Account,Customer name.

We want to add some ordering to show sharepoint default search result.
Orderig means if user enters word "Monitor" in simple search box,
then result should appear in below way,

First all those document should appear in result who have word "Monitor" in its custom column Account,
then all documents should appear who have word "Monitor" in its custom column Customer name
and finally all documents who have word "Monitor" in its document content.

Is there any way by which I can implement this search result ordering in sharepoint?

Thanks in advance..